# Inline styles breaks CSP in create-react-app

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, content-security-policy

I've been working on an app for a while using create-react-app. I recently updated to the latest version of React and it seems to have implemented a new CSP.

This is now throwing between 30–40 violations when I try to load any page in my app. The offending code is highlighted by Chrome devtools - here's an example:
[image: screenshot]

In my code, this example is used in `User.js`, and defined in `User.css`. I can't understand why this is being rendered this way, thus breaking my CSP.

For context, this is what `csp.json` looks like:

```
{
  "dev": {
    "default-src": ["'self'", "https://*.googleapis.com"],
    "style-src": ["'self'", "https://*.googleapis.com"]
  },
  "prod": {
    "default-src": ["'self'", "https://*.googleapis.com"],
    "style-src": ["'self'", "https://*.googleapis.com"],
    "connect-src": ["'self'", "https://*.googleapis.com"]
  }
}
```

In Chrome, the source location for the issue seems to be `injectStylesIntoStyleTag.js`.

This is completely breaking my app, so I'd appreciate any ideas.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You have a few options:

1. Rewrite injectStylesIntoStyleTag.js to self hosted .css file(s) to remove inline style.
2. If there are a limited set of styles to be inserted: Find the hash of all of them and add to style-src.
3. Set a nonce in your style-src that changes with every pageload and propagates to the styles set in injectStylesIntoStyleTag.js
4. Allow 'unsafe-inline' in style-src, this may not be too risky as your other CSP sources are strict, see https://scotthelme.co.uk/can-you-get-pwned-with-css/.

Comment: Thanks. Option 1 was my first choice, but the .css is already self-hosted (I think... it's just in a file alongside my component.js file). 

I looked into Option 2, but couldn't work out how to find the hash. Would it be the base64 hash in the `sourceMappingUrl` tag? 

Worth noting that `injectStylesIntoStyleTag.js` is in `node-modules/style-loader`, which I think is included as a `webpack` dependency.

Comment: Chrome will typically suggest the hash in the error message. Otherwise you can use https://report-uri.com/home/hash and insert whatever is between the tags. If it comes from a dependency you might need to remove that one.